# Why does memcpy fail copying to a local array member of a simple object?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memcpy

Classic memcpy gotcha with C arrays as function arguments. As pointed out below, I have an error in my code but the erroneous code worked in a local context!

I just encountered this weird behaviour in a porting job, where I'm emulating the Macintosh Picture opcode playback using objects. My DrawString object was drawing garbage on playback because it apparently failed to copy the string argument. The following is a test case I wrote - note how a manual copying loop works but memcpy fails. Tracing in the Visual Studio debugger shows the memcpy ovewrites the destination with garbage.

Memcpy on two local Str255 arrays works fine.

When one of them is a member in an object on the stack, it fails (in other testing it also fails when the object is on the heap).

The following sample code shows the memcpy being invoked in an operator=. I moved it there after it failed in a constructor but there was no difference.

```
typedef unsigned char Str255[257];

// snippet that works fine with two local vars
Str255 Blah("\004Blah");
Str255 dest;
memcpy(&dest, &Blah, sizeof(Str255));  // THIS WORKS - WHY HERE AND NOT IN THE OBJECT?

/*!
class to help test  CanCopyStr255AsMember
*/
class HasMemberStr255  {
public:
    HasMemberStr255()
    {
        mStr255[0] = 0;
    }

    HasMemberStr255(const Str255 s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<257; ++i)
        {
            mStr255[i] = s[i];
            if (s[i]==0)
                return;
        }
    }

    /// fails
    void operator=(const Str255 s)  {
        memcpy(&mStr255, &s, sizeof(Str255));
    };
    operator const Str255&() { return mStr255; }

private:
    Str255 mStr255;
};
-

/*!
Test trivial copying technique to duplicate a string
Added this variant using an object because of an apparent Visual C++ bug.
*/
void TestMacTypes::CanCopyStr255AsMember()
{
    Str255 initBlah("\004Blah");
    HasMemberStr255 blahObj(initBlah);
// using the operator= which does a memcpy fails   blahObj = initBlah;

    const Str255& dest = blahObj;  // invoke cast operator to get private back out
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT( dest[0]=='\004' );
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT( dest[1]=='B' );
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT( dest[2]=='l' );
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT( dest[3]=='a' );
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT( dest[4]=='h' );
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT( dest[5]=='\0' );  //  trailing null
}
```

Comment: as I said, it overwrites with garbage when I use memcpy

Comment: The bug is never in the compiler.

Comment: Bugs in platforms are not unheard of, but if memcpy was broken, wouldn't the whole windows world come tumbling down?  My money is on your incorrect & on those pointers in the memcpy call ;)

Comment: "The bug is never in the compiler" well, I have seen a few over the years but note that I was careful to say "appears" :-)

Comment: Yikes, I suspect I am tromping on about 251 bytes of stack with that memcpy(&dest, &Blah...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably a good example of why (in my opinion) it's a bad idea to `typedef` array types.

Unlike in other contexts, in function declarations a parameter of array type is always adjusted to an equivalent pointer type. When an array is passed to the function it always decays into a pointer to the first element.

These two snippets are equivalent:

```
typedef unsigned char Str[257];
Str src = "blah";
Str dst;
memcpy( &dst, &src, sizeof(Str) ); // unconventional
```

---

```
unsigned char src[257] = "blah";
unsigned char dst[257];
memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(unsigned char[257])); // unconventional
```

In this latter case `&dst` and `&src` are both of type `unsigned char (*)[257]` but the value of these pointers are the same as the value of pointers to the first element of each array, which is what `dst` and `src` would decay into if passed directly into `memcpy` like this.

```
memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(unsigned char[257])); // more usual
```

`memcpy` takes `void*` arguments so the types of the original pointers don't matter, only their values.

Because of the rule for parameter declarations (an array type of any or unspecified size is adjusted to the equivalent pointer type), these declarations for `fn` are all equivalent:

```
typedef unsigned char Str[257];
void fn( Str dst, Str src );
```

---

```
void fn( unsigned char dst[257], unsigned char src[257] );
```

---

```
void fn( unsigned char dst[], unsigned char src[] );
```

---

```
void fn( unsigned char* dst, unsigned char* src );
```

Looking at this code, it is more obvious that the values being passed into `memcpy` in this case are pointers to the passed pointers, and not pointers to the actual `unsigned char` arrays.

```
// Incorrect
void fn( unsigned char* dst, unsigned char* src )
{
    memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(unsigned char[257]));
}
```

With a typedef, the error is not so obvious, but still present.

```
// Still incorrect
typedef unsigned char Str[257];
void fn( Str dst, Str src )
{
    memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(Str));
}
```

Comment: Gack! I hate C nuances. It's been a few too many years since I had to wrestle with raw pointer/array idioms.

When I'm doing this kind of port normally I use C++ and Str255 would be a class with operators to catch silliness. Unfortunately, this time, I have to use plain C as there's a heap of backend code that won't compile in C++, even after converting the K&R declarations to ANSI. For other project reasons, I can't vary the code too far from the original.

Comment: Andy Dent, if you wrote good c, you would be confident of avoiding such mistacks; while if you wrote good c++, you would use "struct Str" instead of a simple typedef, and write StrCopy(struct Str *p, struct Str *from), say OOP & encapsulation sense when writing C.

Comment: "if you wrote good c" - I'm porting it, I didn't write it! I can't use structs for things which assume the original Apple definitions which are typedefs. As I said, normally when porting code like this I use objects and operator overloading to get robust types.

Answer (score 5):

You should write `memcpy(mStr255, s, sizeof(Str255));`. Without '&'. `Str255` is already a pointer. That's according to C++ Standard 4.2:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N  T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Why does it work somewhere? There are two different pointers (for `mStr255` and `&mStr255`) and they has different types — `unsigned char *` and `unsigned char (*)[257]`. The address of the array is the same as the address of the
first element in the array, but when you pass it as argument to a function you will get address of variable on the stack. By typefing `Str255` you are hide the difference. Check the following sample:

```
unsigned char Blah[10] = "\004Blah";

struct X
{
    void f1( unsigned char(&a)[10] ) // first case (1)
    {
      void* x1 = &a; // pointer to array of unsigned char
      void* x2 = a;  // pointer to unsigned char due to implicit conversion array-to-pointer
    }
    void f2( unsigned char* a )     // second case (2)
    {
      void* x1 = &a; // pointer to variable 'a' which is on the stack
      void* x2 = a;  // pointer to unsigned char
    }
    unsigned char x[10];
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    X m;
    m.f1( Blah ); // pass by reference
    m.f2( Blah ); // implicit array-to-pointer conversion

    return 0;
}
```

When you are write `void f( Str255 a )`, it is equal to the second case.

Comment: Yes, that worked!

So, why does it work with two local variables?

I am feeling stupid, I cut this code down from 
memcpy(&a[0], &b[1], somesize); which was moving stuff up as well as copying.

Comment: in the case of local variables, you are overwriting the unused stack, say [...used stack space|Blaha|dest|unused stack space...], that is, you written 257 bytes from the position of "dest" toward unused direction.

Comment: Please try to figure out the values of dest and &dest etc (the stack) by adding printf("%p, %p, %p, %p\n", &dest, &Baha, dest, Baha) and share with us.

Comment: I don't think that 'luck' has anything to do with it... just seen your edit, you make the rules clearer, now. Perhaps you can just remove the reference to being lucky?

Answer (score -3):

If I'm reading correctly (and my C++ is a little rusty), your class never actually allocates space for the mStr variable.  You declare it (but don't appear to allocate it) in the private section, and you initialize the first element to 0 in the constructor, but you don't appear to every actually construct a Str255 object.

You may need to replace the private declaration with `Str255 mStr()`, or you may need to do something in the constructor, like `mStr = new Str255()`

Comment: Yes, you're rusty. Str255 is an old-fashioned C array so allocates space inherently.

Comment: The member "Str255 mStr255" in the original post's code snippet could be expanded to "unsigned char mStr255[255]", which does use memory within that allocated for it's HasMemberStr255 instance.